# How to go around a truthy statement here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was trying to implement a navbar functionality in my web app which should be switching the information rendered based on a boolean residing in my redux status. Now, when the user is not logged in, the object fetched using my used selector is an empty one which means that is a truthy value hence not enabling me to toggle the element on the navabr as i wish. Is there a way to do that without modifying my redux status ?

Thank you in advance.

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes, Link, Redirect, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import SearchBar from "./components/searchBar";
import Main from './components/main';
import Login from './components/login';
import Register from './components/register';

let linkStyle = { textDecoration: "none", color: "white" };

function App() {

  // fetching redux status
  let user = useSelector(state => state.loginStatus.user)
  let loginStatus = useSelector(state => state.loginStatus.isLoggedIn)
  console.log(loginStatus)

  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);


  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loginStatus) {
      setIsLoggedIn(loginStatus)
      setAvatar(user)
    }
  }, [loginStatus, isLoggedIn, isActive, avatar])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="logo"><Link to={'/'} onClick={() => setIsActive(false)}><img src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/201/201623.png' /></Link></div>
        <h1 className="title">Travel.com</h1>
        {
          isLoggedIn && (<ul className='menu'>
            <li className="link"><Link style={linkStyle} to='/login' onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}>Log-in</Link></li>
            <li className="link"><Link style={linkStyle} to='/register' onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}>Register</Link></li>
          </ul>)
        }
        { /*
          isLoggedIn && (
            <div className="avatar">
              <h6> Hi avatar.user_name!</h6>
            </div>
          ) */
        }

      </nav>
```

Comment: so check that a property is set `if (loginStatus?.user)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then a simple solution could be to check if the object is empty using something like: `Boolean(Object.keys(logInStatus).length)`
this will return `false` if `logInStatus` is an empty object, and `true` if it has any properties. You would pass this as the argument into `setIsLoggedIn()` in your useEffect().

You said you don't want to change the Redux store, however I would call into question the naming of the `isLoggedIn` property. By starting a property with `is` the name implies that it is a boolean value, or at the very least that it will coerse into a boolean value which corresponds to its name. This is something to watch out for as someone who doesn't know the codebase well would most likely end up making an assumption based on conventions, resulting in a situation like this with code behaving the opposite way to how you would expect.